# How do I cast a 16 bit 'short' into a 32-bit integer in C#?

Tags: c#, casting

I have a 16 bit signed number coming in from hardware.  I want to caste it into an `Int32`.

When I cast it as a `short`, it works occasionally when the number is negative.  Most of the time however, I get a `first chance exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred`.

Here is my code:

```
int M1;
M1 = (short)(INBuffer[3] << 8) + INBuffer[2];
```

How do I cast a 16 bit short to a 32 bit integer in C#?

Comment: What is the type of `INBuffer`? Can you show us its declaration?

Comment: If you're trying to get 32-bit values, why are you casting to `short`?

Comment: Here is a guess, which may be refuted by your answers to my questions above. If `INBuffer` contains `short`s, then the left shift can't produce an `OverflowException` (shift operators in C# just silently discard any bits shifted off the end of the result) but the addition can; it might e.g. be trying to add 32000 to 32000. What behaviour do you actually need in that case? If you just want to do what C would do and throw away high bits, you can use `unchecked`. If not, well, the answer will depend on what you *do* want.

Comment: There are two ways to cast a short to an int in C#: implicitly ans explicitly.  The first: `int intValue = (int)shortValue;`  The second: `int intValue = shortValue;`  In other words, you haven't given us enough information to help you.  What is the type of `INBuffer`?  What are the values of `INBuffer[3]` and `INBuffer[2]` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Gareth - thank you and sorry I did not provide enough info.  InBuffer is a byte array.  If I cast as int, the error goes away.  However -1 displays as 65535.  When I cast as short, -1 occasionally appears on my form as -1, but more often I get the OverflowException.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `INBuffer` is a byte array, you can safely cast to a `ushort` but not a `short`. This is because if the highest bit of the higher order byte is 1, the value is too large for a signed short once it is bitshifted.

In your case, if you want an `int`, no need to cast at all - the bit shift outputs an `int`, and the addition of a `byte` again leaves an `int` - you're already there...

Comment: [citation required].  byte b = 0xff; var s = (short)b;

Comment: @Hans - if I understand your point, then I probably didn't make mine clearly enough. I've edited the end of the first paragraph.

Comment: Could I have an explanation for the -1 please? Happy to accept it, but don't think it's unreasonable to expect an explanation...